# Simulating System Wide Touch Events on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-privateapi

I need to programmatically add touch events to iOS devices **system wide** without using a jailbreak; how do I do this?

Preferably I'd like to use a private API to do this running in an app in the background. I am aware that doing this prevents my app's availability on the app store; this is however a private app so it isn't a problem.