# iOS Private API: lock device and power off the screen

Tags: ios, jailbreak, lockscreen, tweak

I'm making an app for **jailbreak** that lock the device when the user launch the app. I've tried `GSEventLockDevice();` from `GraphicsServices.framework` but this does not work properly because it locks the screen but does not power off the screen. Is there another way to lock the screen without `MobileSubstrate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as another alternative, [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944387/119114), which uses `SBDimScreen()`.  You could use that **in conjunction with** `GSEventLockDevice()`.

It appears that you may now (iOS 5+) need to add an *entitlement* to your app to use this call successfully.  If you haven't done that before, [here is an example of how to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11093442/119114).  Obviously, in this case, the entitlement in question must be changed to `com.apple.backboard.client`.

You also might see if @VictorRonin has experimented with this, as he commented on the question I linked to.  I tested `SBDimScreen()` on a jailbroken iOS 4.2.1 device, but my newer devices are currently unavailable to run this test.  I'll try it later on iOS 5.x and post an update.

**Note:** the answer I linked to from Elias has a **different** call altogether for iOS 6.

Comment: I'm learning MobileSubstrate, maybe is easier than this... Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Nate, would you give me a hand for multi-touch simulating?Very appreciate it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907811/how-to-simulate-multi-touch-with-gsevent

Comment: it's not working on IOS 7, instead console shows an warning  (<Warning>: -[BKWorkspaceServerManager _handleEvent:] Unknown GSEvent, type = 1014; Ignoring.
)

Comment: @ShabiTech, many private APIs stopped working (or began requiring entitlements) in iOS 7.  If you want to know how to do this for iOS 7/8, you should post a **new** question.  This question and answer should be preserved for historical purposes.  If a new solution is needed for iOS 7, we need a separate question for that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at these several questions:

[Simulating System Wide Touch Events on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221086/simulating-system-wide-touch-events-on-ios)

[Simulating System Wide Touch Events in iOS without jailbreaking the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415669/simulating-system-wide-touch-events-in-ios-without-jailbreaking-the-device)

[How to send a touch event to iPhone OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746452/how-to-send-a-touch-event-to-iphone-os/10515571#10515571)

The idea is that you can simulate system wide events. One of events is power down event. If you simulate it, it will turn off device and will lock it.

BTW. You may be interested to google more on GSEvent which is the key for even simulation.

Here are couple of useful links:

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/GSEvent

http://networkpx.blogspot.com/2009/08/gsevent-recording-and-playback-in-30.html

Also, this approach isn't limited to jailbroken phones. It works on jailed phone too (however, you won't be able to post it to AppStore).

Comment: is there an example of this methods?

Comment: Look at this. However, it could be outdate (I believe it was designed for iOS 3.0): http://code.google.com/p/hid-support/source/browse/trunk/hidspringboard/Tweak.xm?spec=svn82&r=82

Comment: @VictorRonin, would you do me a favor about multi-touch simulating?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907811/how-to-simulate-multi-touch-with-gsevent I very appreciate it.

Comment: @Bob: Sorry, I have never tried multi-touch simulation. BTW. Be careful with this approach. People reported problems on iOS 7

Comment: @VictorRonin, thank you for answer,but what's the problems reported on iOS 7?

Comment: @Bob: I saw following question and made assumption that Apple added entitlements to use this API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573572/gscopypurplenamedportappid-in-graphicsservices-is-deprecated-in-ios7