# Programmatically lock iPhone screen in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I know that we can call `GSEventLockDevice ();` from the `GraphicsServices.framework` to lock the screen in `iOS 6` and older version, as explained by **H2CO3** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4348847/1603072). But unfortunately it's not working in `iOS 7`.

**My Question :**
How to lock the iPhone Screen programmatically in `iOS 7` ?

**Note :**  *I don't want this for Appstore.*

Comment: If you want to upload to the AppStore there's no public way to do that.

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862328/ios-private-api-lock-device-and-power-off-the-screen

Comment: @SomeGuy : I don't want this for Appstore.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that lock?

Comment: anyone can help i also want to lock the iphone by code and dont want to submit to appstore

Answer (score 1):

Hi it's not possible in iOS7. You need special entitlement so until there will be a jailbreak you are out of luck

Answer (score 0):

Cant you disable all the `UIGestureRecognizers` for the view?  I do it for buttons all the time.  It is the 'enabled' property for `UIButtons`.  Im sure you can use something like this to achieve satisfactory results.  For the view I think it is `userInteractionEnabled` property for views.  Set your view `userInteractionEnabled` property to NO with a `UISwitch`.

Comment: @JmB I'm assuming the suggestions come from a radio button list of pre-fab responses, so they may not be a perfect fit. Stackoverflow isn't flawless by any means, but hang with us, man!

Comment: MrBoJangles, at the risk of an instant edit, muchas gracias!  First positive experience on this site.  Oh.....UIGesture Enabled BOOL = YES;  I had to add some kind of code gibberish.  ;o)