# Detect lock event on iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios7, foregroundnotification

Greetings for the Day Everyone!!

I want iOS devices with iOS7 version to detect the lock. I did research a lot in it, but didn't find any solution for iOS7.

For Example,

[Programmatically lock iPhone screen in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209887/programmatically-lock-iphone-screen-in-ios-7)

[Lock Unlock events iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone/14213968#14213968)

I have implemented the same feature for iOS6 but it is not working for iOS7.

Checkout the working snipppet for iOS6

```
 // coming back in the foreground
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
{
    // if user lock the screen 
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == 1)
    {
          // coming back after unlocking screen..
    }
}];
```

I have gone through many sources and found there isn't any solution for this in iOS7. Therefor I post the individual question over here, let me know if any one knows how to detect lock event on iOS7 enabled device.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for an answer that works with private (ie jailbroken) or public APIs?

Comment: no with public APIs only

Comment: You could probably hack together a solution that involves `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable` and `applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable` (since that will fire if you have protected data when the screen locks) on the application delegate, but I don't know if Apple will frown on that.

Comment: okay, let me try for it

Comment: no it's not working, it doesn't get called rather

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone

Comment: @VishalKhatri:  it doesn't work for me...