# Programmatically Lock The Screen

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, lockscreen

How do I programmatically lock the screen of the iPhone using C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quick answer**

Apple does not allow you to do so (it's not a C# limitation).

**Longer answer**

There's a [private](https://stackoverflow.com/q/832940/220643) `GSEventLockDevice` API to do so - but it would prevent your application to be on the appstore (Apple will refuse it because of the private API). Also it seems it is [not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19209887/220643) anymore for iOS7.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that sorta makes sense/is expected.