# Programmatically locking iphone (>iOS7)

Tags: ios, swift

i am on a research to find ways to lock iphone programmatically . I have come across a private api "**graphicsservices.framework**" which they say it works only on devices below iOS7. Is there any possible way to do this in devices >iOS7 ?? i know Apple wont accept this , but any private frameworks other than "**graphicsservices.framework**" ? . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hopefully this post should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209887/programmatically-lock-iphone-screen-in-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say but this is not possible in non jailbroke iPhones. There may be a private API for it but apple would reject an app using it, So careful for the same.

You can also see [reference 1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5958089?tstart=0) and [reference 2.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/29693)

Comment: Don't feel sorry to say that because this is Apple's rules and regulations. ;)