# Why GSEventLockDevice() not working in ios 7?

Tags: objective-c

I am using GSEventLockDevice() in ios 5 & 6 working fine but not working in iOS 7. 
why GSEventLockDevice not working in iOS 7?

Please give me a valuable reason.

Answer (score -1):

`GSEventLockDevice()` is not a public iOS API function. This worked in iOS 5 and 6 because Apple didn't restrict it properly. Chances are if you uploaded the app for iOS 5 and 6 the app would have been denied it because it's a **private API**.

If you are developing for jailbroken devices [read this how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862328/ios-private-api-lock-device-and-power-off-the-screen).

---

Just to make it clear, programmatically locking an iOS device will get your app rejected.

Comment: Care to explain why the -1?