# ios how to close screen when user click a button

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to close screen(**device go to sleep**) when user click a button.

I already tried below code,but not work.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

and

```
NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.06 ];
[NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
```

Comment: You mean, you want to send the device to sleep (block the screen)? It's not possible.

Comment: As for your code, the first line forces the device's screen to always be on (the opposite of what you want, I believe), and the second one just freezes the current thread for 60 milliseconds.

Comment: Why do you want to implement such functionality?

Comment: @FreeNickname,Because my fd want a app that he click the app,let the screen of device to sleep.so i make it to him

Comment: so  send the device to sleep, It's not possible? can do that use ios private api or other way?

Comment: It might be possible via private APIs/jailbreak. This might help you: [iOS private API lock device and power off the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862328/ios-private-api-lock-device-and-power-off-the-screen). I, personally, unfortunately, didn't have much experience with private APIs/jailbreak, so I'm unlikely to help you on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use private API (will not be accepted by Apple), there is a solution.

Use **GSEventLockDevice** in the **GraphicsServices.framework**

This solution works, but you won't be able to put your App on AppStore, it will only be OK for internal uses Apps

MORE ABOUT YOUR CODE :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Is for prevent your device to lock after the Idle time set by user on his Settings.

```
NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.06 ];
[NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
```

Putting a Thread to sleep, has nothing to do with locking a device. You probably experienced an app Freeze for about 0.06 second when testing this...